# JSP Error Unable to locate tag attribute info for tag attribute aria-describedby spring form

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jquery-ui, spring-form

I am trying to add aria-describedby to springform. It's throwing a JSP error.
When I tried to use the same aria-* attribute in div tag those are working in the same page.
aria-* is not working for spring form. It's working in div in the same jsp file.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You might adding wrong id for aria-describeby. Please add sample code. Doc for aria-describeby:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute

Comment: No, I have added the correct id. I did verify that.

Comment: I suggest you to add the code with the `aria-describedby` tag, to your question.

Comment: I mean, attribute. And check if the attribute's value (i.e. the element's ID) is not actually a reserved (JSP/Java/etc.) keyword.. Well, just in case.

Comment: Would love to help, but you don't have any of your code shared. This could be accomplished many many different ways, but we want to see how _you_ are trying to do it so we can help. Please post relevant code examples! :D

Comment: attributes are working when I added it for normal html tags ex input type text. Its not working when I add those to spring form tags.

Comment: I did work around used html input types and added hidden form variables and set those values in form in java script. Its bandage fix. I hate bandages. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the workaround,

Added HTML elements and used aria-* to HTML elements.

Added hidden spring form values and set hidden form values in javascript.

It's not the correct way of doing. It's Workaround. it's not a proper fix.